# Swift - type of expression is ambigious without more context

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

I am trying to make an extension for Alamofire in Swift, and have this code:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

protocol JsonResponse
{
    init?(json : NSObject)
}

extension Request
{
    func responseObject<T : JsonResponse, Error: ErrorType>(completionHandler : Result<T,Error> -> Void) -> Self
    {
        return responseJSON(completionHandler: {r  in
            let result = r.result
            guard result.isSuccess else {
                completionHandler(.Failure(result.error!))
                return
            }
            let obj : T? = T(json : result.value as! NSObject)
            let success : Result<T,Error> = .Success(obj!)
            completionHandler(success)
        })

    }
}
```

Which gives me the compiler error:

> Error:(21, 36) type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Interestingly, when I comment out this line, it compiles:

```
// completionHandler(.Failure(result.error!))
```

How do I give Swift enough type information to make this work ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that is doesn't know the type of the Result type (`.Failure(result.error!)`) is. Being the failure case there is nothing that tells the compiler what T will be.

You can write it out in full `Result<T,Error>.Failure(result.error!)`.

Comment: I'm slightly surprised that being the argument to the completion handler didn't provide sufficient type context.

Answer (score 1):

I made it compile with this:

```
completionHandler(Result<T,Error>.Failure(result.error! as! Error))
```

One problem is the type inferring and the other is that result.error is a optional NSError. I don't know if NSError can be cast to ErrorType tho..

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Request
{
    // this function declares return type Self (aka Request)
    func responseObject<T : JsonResponse, Error: ErrorType>(completionHandler : Result<T,Error> -> Void) -> Self
    {
        // here you return ... I don't know, but the type
        // is return type of the function responseJSON,
        // probably Void too
        return responseJSON(completionHandler: {r  in
            let result = r.result
            guard result.isSuccess else {
                completionHandler(.Failure(result.error!))
                // here you return Void
                return
            }
            let obj : T? = T(json : result.value as! NSObject)
            let success : Result<T,Error> = .Success(obj!)
            completionHandler(success)
        })

    }
}
```

i guess you need something like

```
func responseObject<T : JsonResponse, Error: ErrorType>(completionHandler : Result<T,Error> -> Void) -> Void
```